# How to generate python type hints in generated grpc code

Tags: python, grpc, type-hinting, grpc-python

Can PEP compliant type hints be automatically added to generated source code, or dynamically created, for python and gRPC? Specifically in the [basics tutorial](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/python/basics/#simple-rpc-1) in the client section for `feature = stub.GetFeature(point)` I would like my IDE to know and check that point is type `Point` in the `*_pb2.py` and feature is type `Feature` with an attribute `location: Point`. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type hints aren't yet (!?) available for Python gRPC, see [Issue 29041](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/29041)

You can generate type hints for the Protobuf messages only using the `--pyi_out=${PWD}` flag when running `protoc` directly or indirectly with `python3 -m grpc.tools.protoc`

Answer (score 3):

For protubuf generated files (`*_pb2.py`), we have [a PR in review](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/pull/32872) to add pyi files. And for gRPC Python in general, I'm currently working on it and it should be finished by end of this quarter.